Расшифруйте текст пожалуйста

Эяырь эъчплюж, ыъчцънъпвж, ъмёрпфщсщщър эъущлщфр, унягфю цлц
алщюлэюфгрэцфх ьъшлщ. Цлц к ыфэлч ьлщрр ф н пщрнщфцр щъшрь щъчз цлтпжх
фу эъчплю мжч ъэъмрщщжш, цлц ф юфы мьъщф. Рпфщэюнрщщлк эбътрэюз -
Ычлюл, эъуплсю ыэф-улефюя нъцьяо щъэфюрчк, цъюъьър улефелрю ъю ыячз.
Чфдз фупрчфр № 62 фчф шъещжх ичрцюьъшлощфю шътрю ыьъмфюз плщщжх
ъоьлщфгфюрчз.
Лцюфнлвфк "Ыъцьън юзшж" ыъплсю эфощлч нэрш щъэфюрчкш, л н ырьняй
ъгрьрпз Унрьй фчф тр У-002 ф 4Р-ЬЮ. Ыъчщър эцьжюфр ячфц ъ ыьъфэбъпкерш
щл юрььфюъьфф ГЛУ. Пчк эъуплщфр эяырь эъчплю нжмфьлчф ъгрщз щрэяьлущжх
ыъпбъп, нукюз юъоъ тр Йпфщл Ш.М. - нрюрьлщ нъхщж, тфч н прьрнщф, щъ
фшрщщъ роъ Цягрьрщцъ ф Цъщънлчън ьрдфчф улмьлюз ыькш фу мъчзщфвж.
Тлчцъ Ыъьъэсщцънл, гюъ янфпрч цлц ычъюз эшрдфнлйю эъ эюлчзй.
4Р-ЬЮ - нжмьлщ ыяюсш энърх тфнягрэюф ф эыъэъмщъэюзй шлщфыячфьънлюз
чйпзшф, ьлщрр мжч чфгщжш ъбьлщщфцъш Юяьгфщэцъоъ Н.Ф., фунрэющъ гюъ ъщ
фэыжюжнлч эюьлщщжр эрцэялчзщжр нчргрщфк ц роъ пъгрьф Чфур, мрпщжх
ьрмсщъц. Цъщюьъчсь-β мжчъ чрогр.


Цезарь простой  И->Ф

По тексту бросается в глаза что буква И заменена на букву Ф. Если плохо знакомы с правилами языка на котором написан текст, то можно и перебором.
Шифр Цезаря - все буквы смещаются на определенное число. Тут это число 12.
Делаем табличку трансляции и переводим.
abc = 'абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя'
c = abc.index('ф') - abc.index('и')
bca = abc[c:] + abc[:c]
tr = str.maketrans(bca+bca.upper(),abc+abc.upper())
print(text.translate(tr))


...
4Е-РТ - выбран путём своей живучести и способностью манипулировать
людьми, ранее был личным охранником Турчинского В.И., известно что он
испытывал странные сексуальные влечения к его дочери Лизе, бедный
ребёнок. Контролёр-β было легче.


Зачем на такое отвечать?

@wchistow я отвечаю на этом сайте не для того чтоб помочь другим. Только для того чтоб потренировать себя. Учить дурака - самый простой способ научиться самому.
